# Convert JSON Post, into Python List

Tags: python, json, list

Hello guys I have this list from json post:
The Json:

```
{"Array":"[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6), (6, 7)]"}
```

I need to transform it in this format:

```
type<class 'list'>
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6), (6, 7)]
```

What i have tried:

```
def getData():
    json_data = request.get_json()
    newList=[]
    [newList.extend([v]) for k,v in json_data.items()]
    print("type:",type(newList))
    # OUTPUT: <class 'list'>
    print("list:",newList)
    # OUTPUT:['[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6), (6, 7)]']
    print("type 1:",type(newList[0]))
    # OUTPUT:<class 'str'>
    print("list 1 :",newList[0])
    # OUTPUT:[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6), (6, 7)]
```

In the first its a list but not in the format that i need, in the second its not a list but its in the format that i need.

Thanks for help!

Comment: use `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert string representation of list to a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be what you are looking for.

```
import ast
data = {"Array":"[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6), (6, 7)]"}
print(ast.literal_eval(data["Array"]))
```

prints:

```
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6), (6, 7)]
```

For more information about abstract syntax trees (ast) and literal_eval I refer you to the python docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna get downvotes for using exec. So I highly discourage usage of exec. But, here is a hack that works:

```
import json

jsonStr =  '{"Array":"[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6), (6, 7)]"}'
jsonObj = json.loads(jsonStr)
exec("newList = "+jsonObj["Array"])

print(type(newList))
print(newList)
```